# Characters moving through walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get characters to move around by randomly going left/right/forward at turns, and for the most part the characters do that, but every once in a while they walk through the walls, and I don't want that to happen. Is there anything you can see in my code that I am missing?

The walls have colliders on them, and so do the circles, but the circles colliders are just a trigger because I want the circles to be able to go through each other, just not through the walls.

It seems like the character turns, and some time turns again towards a wall.

Here is a video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOfGn3bsuLA

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class Character : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    protected Transform frontRaycast, leftRaycast, rightRaycast;
    protected List<int> lastPossibleDirs = new List<int>();
    protected int lastDir;
    protected bool changed = false;
    protected bool forward, left, right;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        frontRaycast = transform.FindChild("FrontRaycast").transform;
        leftRaycast = transform.FindChild("LeftRaycast").transform;
        rightRaycast = transform.FindChild("RightRaycast").transform;
    }

    void Update(){
        // Test for a wall in front and on sides
        forward = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, frontRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));
        left = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, leftRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));
        right = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, rightRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));

        // Add each direction to the list of possible turns
        List<int> possibleDirs = new List<int>();
        if(!forward){
            possibleDirs.Add(0);
        }
        if(!left){
            possibleDirs.Add(1);
        }
        if(!right){
            possibleDirs.Add(2);
        }
        int dir = 0;
        if(possibleDirs.Count > 0){
            dir = (int)possibleDirs[Random.Range(0, possibleDirs.Count)];
        }

        if(changed){
            // Move forward with left or right option
            if(lastPossibleDirs.Exists(element => element == 0) && lastPossibleDirs.Exists(element => element > 0) && (left || right) && lastDir == 0){
                changed = false;
            }
            // Left
            else if(lastPossibleDirs.Exists(element => element == 1) && left && lastDir == 1){
                changed = false;
            }
            // Right
            else if(lastPossibleDirs.Exists(element => element == 2) && right && lastDir == 2){
                changed = false;
            }
        }else{
            switch(dir){
                case 0:
                    if(!left || !right){
                        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,0));
                        changed = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,90));
                    changed = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,-90));
                    changed = true;
                    break;
            }
            lastDir = dir;
            lastPossibleDirs = possibleDirs;
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of where the detection areas are located on the character

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist thing I would do is uncheck trigger on your circle and make use of

```
Physics2d.IgnoreLayerCollision(circle layer)
```

in the `Awake()`